# Vuetify concatenate two fields in v-select's item-text

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

Is there a way to concatenate two fields together in a v-select's item-text field?

I have it working for the drop down list values, but the visible entry doesn't show the two fields.

Problem is here: item-text="'${data.item.name}, ${data.item.group}'"

Code:

```
`<v-select label="Select" v-bind:items="people" v-model="e11"
  item-text="'${data.item.name}, ${data.item.group}'"
  item-value="name" max-height="auto" autocomplete >
  <template slot="item" slot-scope="data">
    <v-list-tile-content>
      <v-list-tile-title 
         v-html="`${data.item.name}, ${data.item.group}`">
      </v-list-tile-title>
      <v-list-tile-sub-title 
         v-html="data.item.group">
      </v-list-tile-sub-title>
    </v-list-tile-content>
   </template> 
</v-select>`
```

Pen Example:  https://codepen.io/anon/pen/dJveWM?editors=1010

Thank you

Comment: Can you be more clear as of what your problem is?

Comment: Instead of showing the Name Group field values, [object Object] is displayed.

Comment: Have you taken the time to check my answer?

Comment: Looks great via Codepen, will try it in our application on Tuesday.  Thank you

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to define a template not only for the slot `item` but also for the slot `selection` when using `<v-select>`:

```
<template slot="selection" slot-scope="data">
  <v-chip
    close
    @input="data.parent.selectItem(data.item)"
    :selected="data.selected"
    class="chip--select-multi"
    :key="JSON.stringify(data.item)"
  >
    <v-avatar>
      <img :src="data.item.avatar">
    </v-avatar>
    {{ data.item.name }}
  </v-chip>
</template>
```

See

> https://vuetifyjs.com/components/selects#6-scoped-slots

for reference.

This can also be a much simpler solution like the one you're trying to achieve:

```
<template slot="selection" slot-scope="data">
  {{ data.item.name }}, {{ data.item.group }}
</template>
```

Also see it in action:

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/PEpaMM?editors=1011

Comment: Then please mark this answer as solving your problem.

Comment: Usefull answer, thanks. In my case the text become light blue. How can I avoid this effect?

Comment: @connexo, this solution works to display both fields in both the item and selection, but doesn't allow for autocomplete based on both fields.  Any way to adjust for autocomplete of both?

Answer (score 5):

For David Folkner: you can add the `:filter="customFilter"` property to the autocomplete component and then add in the *methods* block the *customFilter* function that achieves the custom search.

For example, if your *items* list is composed by n item objects with *id*, *function* and *description* properties, you should do this for searching through both function and description properties:

**Autocomplete component:**

```
<v-autocomplete v-model="itemSelected" :items="items" required box chips label="Select an Item" item-value="id" item-text="description" :filter="customFilter">
    <template slot="selection" slot-scope="data">
        <v-chip :selected="data.selected" class="chip--select">
            {{data.item.function}} - {{ data.item.description }}
        </v-chip>
    </template>
    <template slot="item" slot-scope="data">
        <v-list-tile-content>
            <v-list-tile-title v-html="data.item.function +' - '+ data.item.description"></v-list-tile-title>
        </v-list-tile-content>
    </template>
</v-autocomplete>
```

**methods:**

```
methods: {
    customFilter (item, queryText, itemText) {
        const textOne = item.function.toLowerCase()
        const textTwo = item.description.toLowerCase()
        const searchText = queryText.toLowerCase()
        return textOne.indexOf(searchText) > -1 || textTwo.indexOf(searchText) > -1
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, *this* is actually the response I was looking for. I guess the original question can be understood both ways

Answer (score 3):

```
<v-select
  :items="unitTypes"
  item-text="value"
  item-value="id"
  v-model="formData.unit_type"
  prepend-icon="mdi-ammunition"
  label="Unit Types"
  required
  :error-messages="errors"
>
  <template slot="selection" slot-scope="data">
    {{ data.item.value }} {{ data.item.type }}
  </template>
  <template slot="item" slot-scope="data">
    {{ data.item.value }} {{ data.item.type }}
  </template>
</v-select>
```

Answer (score 1):

We are using

```
"vue-cli-plugin-vuetify": "2.0.5",
"vue-eslint-parser": "^7.10.0",
"vue-template-compiler": "^2.6.11",
```

And the following worked well for us.

```
<v-autocomplete v-model="data.alarmInfoId" :items="dbQueryResult" item-value="prop3" :item-text="(row) => {return row.prop1+ ' - ' + row.prop2;}"/>
```

dbQueryResult is a list of items returned from an API call
prop1, prop2, and prop3 are properties on each row in dbQueryResult

I believe that this will work with v-select as well.  Though we use v-autocomplete so that users can type search in larger lists.

Answer (score 1):

***item-text*** can accept a function

```
:item-text="item => `${item.first_value} ${item.second_value}`"
```

Answer (score 0):

use  slot="selection"

```
<template slot="selection" slot-scope="item">
  {{ item.name }}-{{ item.group }}
</template>
```

To know more slot
https://vuetifyjs.com/en/api/v-autocomplete/#slots