# How to concatenate two fields in v-autocomplete item-text vuetify

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

I'm looking for a way to concatenate two fields in a v-autocomplete item-text field,

This is my code:

```
            <ol>
              <li>
                  <v-autocomplete
                    placeholder="Search a person"
                    prepend-inner-icon="mdi-magnify"
                    chips
                    clearable
                    dense
                    v-model="counterpart1"
                    item-value="id"
                    item-text="first_value"
                    :items="enrolled1"
                  />
              </li>
            </ol>
```

I expect something like this:

```
            <ol>
              <li>
                  <v-autocomplete
                    placeholder="Search a person"
                    prepend-inner-icon="mdi-magnify"
                    chips
                    clearable
                    dense
                    v-model="counterpart1"
                    item-value="id"
                    item-text="first_value + second_value"
                    :items="enrolled1"
                  />
              </li>
            </ol>
```

I tried this:

```
item-text="first_value + second_value"
```

And this:

```
:item-text="`${first_value}, ${second_value}`"
```

But I got `[object Object]`. I found this similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48012076/vuetify-concatenate-two-fields-in-v-selects-item-text/48013260) but I think my case is a bit difference and I can't understand, how to change it in that way.

Any help will be appreciated

Comment: Can you confirm that `first_value` and `second_value` are both Strings? The fact that you got `[object Object]` makes me think that at lease one of them is an object instead of a String. Try console logging them.

Comment: @camaulay either ```enrolled1``` and ```enrolled2``` are objects that takes values from the same endpoint, so ```item-text="first_value"``` display the value, but I can't achieve to concatenate two values

Comment: Can you please update your question , by adding the value stored in enrolled1 array of objects, this really helps to solve the issue faster

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Use a function to render the `item-text`.

```
:item-text="getItemText"
```

Then, in your `methods`:

```
getItemText(item) {
    return `${item.first_value} ${item.second_value}`;
}
```

Comment: You wrote a typo in ```first_value}n```, but that worked for me: ```return `${item.first_value} ${item.second_value}`;``` thanks!

Answer (score 3):

***item-text*** can accept a function

```
:item-text="item => `${item.first_value} ${item.second_value}`"
```

The first answer is correct however you can use this if you do not want to declare another function